# zend not using columns, and selecting everything

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have the following code

```
$result = $handle->select()->from('store_details')
                               ->where('store_details.store_id=?', $id)
                               ->columns('store_details.store_name');
                               //->query(ZEND_DB::FETCH_OBJ);
```

However, when I run it, the entire row is selected, not just the column I wanted.
Here is the output from __toString

```
SELECT `store_details`.*, `store_details`.`store_name` 
FROM `store_details` WHERE (store_details.store_id=8)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `columns()` method is for *adding* columns to an existing **from** or **join**. The correct way to build your query is:

```
$result = $handle->select()->from('store_details','store_details.store_name')->where('store_details.store_id=?', $id);
```

You need to specify the columns you want as the second parameter to the from() method, as a string if it is just one column, or as an array for multiple columns. From the [`Zend_Db_Select docs`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html):

> In the second argument of the from()
>   method, you can specify the columns to
>   select from the respective table. If
>   you specify no columns, the default is
>   "*", the SQL wildcard for "all
>   columns".
>
> You can list the columns in a simple
>   array of strings, or as an associative
>   mapping of column alias to column
>   name. If you only have one column to
>   query, and you don't need to specify a
>   column alias, you can list it as a
>   plain string instead of an array.

Comment: This is good to know (!) since the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Db/Select/Zend_Db_Select.html#columns) doesn´t mention the part about _adding_ columns: "Specifies the columns used in the FROM clause."

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the select object (means the `from()` was called before), you should use `$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);` and then call `columns()` as you do in the example.